# Нужно ли экранировать данные в Codeigniter при такой конструкции запроса

Tags: codeigniter

```
$data = arrray();
$this->db->insert_batch('article_category', $data);
```

Нужно ли для значений массива *$data* применять функцию экранирования *$this->db->escape()*?

Comment: Если вы боитесь, что пустой массив создаст из ниоткуда sql-инъекуцию - то нет, такого не будет. Другой вопрос - зачем такое сохранять в БД.

Comment: Я лишь привел пример, что на входе массив..лень было перечислят элементы массива

Comment: Так же он позволяет делать запросы более безопасными за счет автоматического экранирования значений.
___
Из справки Класс Active Record

Comment: Все верно, при использовании Active Record вам не надо экранировать значения вручную.